# Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with this program? (C)

Tags: c

I am doing the easy challenge on /r/dailyprogrammer in C.  I actually managed to write over a hundred lines of code, and spend a couple hours total on it (usually I end up chickening out), and figure out all the compiler errors.  But now, when I run it, I immediately get a segfault. What I'm doing wrong?

Yes, it's sort of homework help, but at least I tried before coming here.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN  50
#define LIMIT   20
#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

char* reverse(char *a);
char* ltoa(long i);
long atol(char *a); /* NOTE: Handle leading zeros. */
long palindromize(long p);
int ispalindrome(long p);

/* Meat. */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long p;
    int count, limr;

    p = (long) argv[1];
    count = 0;
    limr = FALSE;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        p = palindromize(p);
        count++;
        if (ispalindrome(p))
        {
            break;
        } else if (count == LIMIT) {
            limr = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (limr)
    {
        printf("It might be a palindrome, but it'd take quite a while to find out.\nLast number reached: %ld\n", p);
    } else {
        printf("Palindrome found!  After %d steps, we've found %ld.\n", count, p);
    }
}

long palindromize(long p)
{
    return (atol(reverse(ltoa(p)))) + p;
}

int ispalindrome(long p)
{
    char *t, *r;

    t = ltoa(p);
    r = reverse(ltoa(p));

    if (t == r)
    {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

/* Utility functions. */

/* Converts string to long integer. */
long atol(char *a)
{
    int i, sign;
    long r;

    for (i = 0; a[i] == '0'; i++)
    {
        i++;
    }

    if (a[0] == '-' || a[-1] == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        sign = 1;
    }

    for (; isdigit(a[i]); i++)
    {
        r = 10 * r + (a[i] - '0');
    }

    return r * sign;
}

/* Converts long integer to string.
   This and reverse are based on the ones in K&R. */
char* ltoa(long n)
{
    char *a;
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)
    {
        n = -n;
    }

    i = 0;
    do
    {
        a[i++] = n % 10 + '0';
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);

    if (sign < 0)
    {
        a[i++] = '-';
    }
    a[i] = '\0';

    return reverse(a);
}

char* reverse(char *s)
{
    int i, j;
    char c;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }

    return s;
 }
```

Comment: `p = (long) argv[1];` does `argv[1]` exist? Also, you need to convert the `char*` to `long` using your `atol` function, casting won't work.

Comment: Actually you don't know what you actually passing as parameter. Please print argv[1]. Then you will get the idea.

Comment: Minor: Aside from `char *a` not having memory for the string, `ltoa(LONG_MIN)` fails.

Comment: `if (t == r) ...` doesn't do what you think. In this case `==` means pointer comparison, in which the operands are considered equal if they have the same address, irrespective of whether they point to identical strings. You want [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: Meaningless title, and you haven't described what your program is supposed to do, or what it actually does instead, or why that is unexpected.

Comment: 'what I'm doing wrong?' - not using a debugger, for one thing.

Comment: How do we know what's going wrong if we don't know what 'going right' should look like? Please tell us what you are trying to achieve and what is actually happening instead! What is your error, output etc?

Comment: Also PLEASE change the title!! These questions are here to help others in the community too, not just to get your homework sorted! I'd make a suggestion but really not sure what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

In `ltoa` you declare `char *a;` but never `malloc` any space for it. When you access `a[i]` it crashes. For problems like this, remember a simple first debugging step is to add print statements everywhere so you can at least pinpoint where the error is occurring.

Looks like your `ispalindrome` is wrong too, but not in a seg fault way. I'll let you figure out why =D

Comment: I get `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘char *’`, in `ispalindrome`.  I got that earlier but don't quite understand why it says that.

Comment: I guess you changed it to `char a[50]`? You can fix it by changing `t` and `r` to `char t[50], a[50]`, and changing all types to char arrays instead. Instead, just `malloc` 50 `char`s for `a`   `char *a = (char*) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));`  and set all of `a` to null characters

Answer (score 0):

```
char* ltoa(long n)
{
    char *a;
    int i, sign;
```

This is, in fact, a very common error. `char *a` is a pointer to a character (possibly a character array). But you don't tell it where the character *are* in memory. So it is pointing to some random location.

You can either reserve characters locally by using `char a[100]` or so, but that will land you with problems on returning from the function. Or you can reserve memory with `char *a = (char *)malloc(100)`. Or you could consider palindromize the input string itself, and leave the memory problems to the caller.